# Deleting row from a table in google docs

Tags: python, google-api, google-docs, google-api-client, google-docs-api

i am trying to implement code in https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/tables#python_1

my full code is shown here

```
from pygdrive3 import service


requests = [{
        'insertText': {
          'location': {
            'index': 5
          },
          'text': 'Hello'
      }
    },
    {
      'deleteTableRow': {
          'tableCellLocation': {
              'tableStartLocation': {
                      'index': 2
              },
              'rowIndex': 1,
              'columnIndex': 1
          },
          'insertBelow': 'true'
      }
    }
  ]

result = service.documents().batchUpdate(documentId= 'DOC_ID', body={'requests': requests}).execute()
```

i would like to delete the last 3 rows in the second table for example.

the error i am running into is:  exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'pygdrive3.service' has no attribute 'documents'

Keeping in mind that i have completed Python Quickstart in google developers, so i have all libraries needed.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and `the error i am running into is: exception has occurred: AttributeError module 'pygdrive3.service' has no attribute 'documents' Keeping in mind that i have completed Python Quickstart in google developers, so i have all libraries needed.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current script?

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you so much for your comment it's really appreciated, The error i having is concerned with the last line of the code `result = service.documents().batchUpdate` where the error is ` exception has occurred: AttributeError module 'pygdrive3.service' has no attribute 'documents'` i would like to just tell the code to delete last 3 rows from 3 table ( since my doc contains more than 1 table ) any help will be highly appriciated!!

Comment: @Tanaike Please see my GitHub File i've created to help you implement my code: (https://github.com/EyadZaeim/MDS2)

Comment: Thank you for replying. What is `from pygdrive3 import service`? From your error message of `exception has occurred: AttributeError module 'pygdrive3.service' has no attribute 'documents'`, I thought that it might not be able to be used for `service.documents().batchUpdate()`. In your script, how about using `service = build('docs', 'v1', credentials=creds)` of the Quickstart? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python)